# How can I merge 3 json files

Tags: python

I have 3 json  data files:

users - `{"user_id":"8a25cdd1".....}`

streamData - `{[{"user_id":"8a25cdd1", "track_id":"c3d3287d", "version":"3"}, ...]}`

trackData - `{"track_id":"c3d3287d", "album_code":"123", "artist":"Bryan Adams"}`

For each `streamData` add a `trackData` record.
For each `user` add the `streamData` array with the `trackData` record.

should look like:

```
{
    "user_id": "8a25cdd1",
    "streamData": [
        {
            "user_id": "8a25cdd1",
            "track_id": "c3d3287d",
            "version": "3",
            "trackData": {
                "track_id": "c3d3287d",
                "album_code": "123",
                "artist": "Bryan Adams"
            }
        },
        # { stream 2 }, { stream 3 }, ...
    ]
}
```

I have struggled for 3 days trying varying methods and I am stuck here:

```
def add_users():
    # open the user records filer
    userTmp = []
    fUsers = open(uPath, 'r')
    jUsers = json.loads(fUsers.read())

    for row in jUsers:
        userTmp = get_streams(dict(row))  
        if len(userTmp) > 0:
            **dict(row).update([userTmp])**  # The bane of my existence is addin the array of records to the parent user_id
    # print(row, file=open(path + 'hcl-user-data.json', 'w'))

def get_streams(urow):
    fStreams = open(sPath, 'r')
    jStreams = json.loads(fStreams.read())
    tmpDict = dict({"StreamData": []})

    for sub in jStreams:
        if urow['user_id'] == sub['user_id']:    # does stream data exist for the current user_id
            tmpDict['StreamData'].append(sub)

    return tmpDict
```

Comment: In Python, function names and variables should be name `lowercase_with_underscores` not `camelCase`

Comment: @Boris, that is no mandatory, developers use the convention their organize defines.

Comment: ThePyGuy is correct. you should use whatever your organization's or team's conventions are.

Comment: Most Stack Overflow users (especially the ones asking basic questions) that are not following the convention are not following it because they don't know about it, not because they're consciously deciding to go against it.

Answer (score 0):

First, transform your data into a dictionary mapping user IDs to a list of stream data

```py
import json

users_filename = "users.json"
streams_filename = "streamData.json"
tracks_filename = "trackData.json"

with open(users_filename) as f:
    users = json.load(f)
with open(streams_filename) as f:
    streams = json.load(f)
with open(tracks_filename) as f:
    tracks = json.load(f)

# create a dictionary mapping track ids to their track data
track_data = {t['track_id']: t for t in tracks}

# then iterate over all the streams and create a dictionary
# mapping a user ID to a list of streams and get the streamed 
# track's data from the dictionary we created on the previous line
users_streams = {}
for stream in streams:
    stream["trackData"] = track_data[stream['track_id']]
    users_streams.setdefault(stream['user_id'], []).append(stream)
```

You can do `print(users_streams)` to check the result, it will be a dictionary mapping user IDs to their list of streams, which should be a better format than the one you want for whatever you want to do with this data.

```json
{
    "8a25cdd1": [
        {
            "user_id": "8a25cdd1",
            "track_id": "c3d3287d",
            "version": "3",
            "trackData": {
                "track_id": "c3d3287d",
                "album_code": "123",
                "artist": "Bryan Adams"
            }
        },
        # { user 8a25cdd1's stream 2 }, { stream 3 }, ...
    ],
    "9b36dee2" [
        # ...
    ],
}
```

If you need to turn the above into the format you asked for in your question:

```py
output = []
for user_id, streams in users_streams.items():
    output.append({"user_id": user_id, "StreamData": streams})
```

---

I used the [`setdefault` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), to set the value of a dictionary to an empty list if we haven't inserted any data for a user ID yet. You can also do this with [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). It's the same as doing this:

```
    if stream['user_id'] not in users_streams:
        users_streams[stream['user_id']] = []
    users_streams[stream['user_id']].append(stream)
```